# Excel IF statement to match keyword to ignore case

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following IF statement

```
If .Cells(r, "L").Value Like "Milestone*" Then
        If UBound(Split(.Cells(r, "L"), ",")) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim v(1 To i)
            v(i) = pasteRowIndex
        End If
```

I need to also include that this keyword is non case sensitive, but I am getting run time errors when I try.

Is there a quick solution?

Comment: If all of your comparisons in the module will be case insensitive, you can place `Option Compare Text` prior to the `Sub ...` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution - put both values in `LCase` (or `UCase`):

```
If LCase(.Cells(r, "L").Value) Like LCase("Milestone*") Then
```

Or just one in `LCase`, and the other one written normally.

```
Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print LCase("Milestonea") Like "milestone*"
    Debug.Print LCase("Milestonea") Like "Milestone*"

End Sub
```